# How to operate on a dataframe column by index

Tags: python, pandas

Following advice I received on StackOverflow, I thought I had solved my `CopyWithWarning problems when using Pandas dataframes, but they are back to bite me. I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe that is the first difference of another column:

```
df[upper_sys_hrt] = df[idx_upper] - df[idx_upper].shift(1)
df[upper_sys_hrt].iloc[0] = d[upper_sys_hrt].iloc[1]
```

This sometimes (not always) gives me a `CopyWithWarning` error. I tried changing this to

```
df[ : , df.get_loc(upper_sys_hrt)] =  df[ : , df.columns.get_loc(idx_upper)] - df[: , df.columns.get_loc(idx_upper)].shift(1)
```

but all i get is an error message:

```
TypeError: '(slice(1, None, None), 3)' is an invalid key
```

I have tried (hunt and peck) changes to the syntax as well as Googling and gotten nowhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have the column's *position*, not the label. To get the label, index back into `df.columns`:

```
col = df.columns[df.get_loc(upper_sys_hrt)]
df[col] = df[col] - df[col].shift()
```

Or just

```
df[col] = df[col].diff()
```

If you're rather work with the index, you can use `iloc`:

```
idx = df.get_loc(upper_sys_hrt)
df.iloc[:,idx] = df.iloc[:,idx].diff()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. To tell you the truth, it's doubly mysterious because df[col] appears functionally identical to df[upper_sys_hrt], which is what i started with, but it's clear that your way does not induce the confusing CopyWithWarnings error, while mine does.. Is there a difference under the hood that's not obvious on the outside?

Comment: @ThomasPhilips Can't say as I don't have all your code. But as a rule of thumb prefer `(i)loc` and `(i)at` are superior methods when it comes to assignment, for more info please take a look at my writeup here: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/4909087).